# Does sentry send errors over http to a central location?

Tags: python, sentry

Little confused how sentry works, does it send errors from various servers over to a central server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install/index.html#running-a-sentry-server):

> The recommended configuration of Sentry involves setting up a separate web server to handle your error logging. This means that any number of Sentry clients simply pass on this information to your primary Sentry server.

You can also configure it to have just one client and server, both residing on the same machine.

Comment: do you know how it passes messages to the main server? http?

Comment: See http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/technical/index.html#writing-a-client for more details on how Sentry clients communicate errors to their server.